# capture the parent of a substring within a larger string

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying to write a pattern to capture a string that's the parent of a specified substring that is within a larger string of text but surrounded by tabs or spaces. So, for example if I have:

```
aosidf asdoij aiosdf capture_this_string_and_its_value oasijdf 
adsf aosidf asdoij aiosdf capture_this_string_and_its_value2 oasijdf oaisjd 
adsf aosidf aiosdf now_capture_in_middle3 oasijdf oaisjd 
adsf aosidf asdoij capture_this_string_and_its_value4 oasijdf oaisjd 


var input_value= $("#input").val(); //the value of all that text taken from a textarea
var needle = "capture";

var re = new RegExp("((.*?)[\s\t]){0,}((.*?)" + needle + "(.*?))[\s\t]+(.*)(\r\n)?", "gmi");

var res = input_value.replace(re, "$3\n");
```

I'm not capturing the value around `(.*?)" + needle + "(.*?)`. I would expect the output to be:

```
capture_this_string_and_its_value
capture_this_string_and_its_value2
now_capture_in_middle3
capture_this_string_and_its_value4
```

But I'm getting bad results.

```
df capture_thi

df capture_thi

df now_capture_in_middle3 oa

doij capture_thi
```

How can I change my pattern?

Comment: Whatever the solution, try to escape all the characters in "needle" var before you construct the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
new RegExp("\\S*" + needle + "\\S*", "gmi")
```

`\S` is any non-whitespace character.

Comment: won't that just capture the needle? the needle could be on the beginning, end, or middle of a string. The idea is to capture the string that contains it.

Comment: @thomas `match` does not require to match the whole string.

Comment: @thomaas - `\S` means not whitespace (capital s).

Comment: @thomas - So 'aosidf asdoij aiosdf `capture_this_string_and_its_value` oasijdf' would match.

Comment: @Gumbo - You probably don't need the multiline modifier (unless its some other meaning).

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var re = new RegExp(".*\\s+(\\S*" + needle + "\\S*)\\s+.*", "gmi");
var res = input_value.replace(re, "$1");
```

Output:

```
capture_this_string_and_its_value
capture_this_string_and_its_value2
now_capture_in_middle3
capture_this_string_and_its_value4
```

Comment: Improved considering Gumbo's answer.

Comment: `[\s\t]` is identical to `\s`. `[^\s\t]` is identical to `\S`

Comment: So this just matches a single item per line. There might be more than one per line.

Comment: @sln for my purposes right now, it is only one item per each line, thank you though. Akhanubis, what do the double slashes mean?

Comment: @thomas, when evaluating just `"\\s"`, the first \ will escape the second so the resulting string will be `\s`. Then `\s` will be passed to the regexp constructor which will convert the string `\s` to `/\s/`. Long story short, you need to escape with \ the \ that will be used to escape the `s` in the regexp. `new RegExp("\\s")` equals `/\s/`.